# html2text strange buffered output issue when writing output file

Tags: php, linux, character-encoding

I'm running the html2text command via PHP exec command to convert HTML to plain text on my iMac. But I'm getting some really strange outputs, letters duplicated, some a random number of times and getting weird characters.

sample output (taken by saving HTML of Stack Overflow homepage and then running through html2text).

*cc*uu_rr_rr_ee_nn_tt_ *cc*oo_mm_mm_uu_nn_ii_tt_yy 
    * *c*h_a_t *b*l_o_g *l*o_g_ *o*u_t
      *S*t_a_c_k_ *O*v_e_r_f_l_o_w

This is happening every time I use the command line program, I have tried various HTML pages.

I don't know a great deal about character encoding and the way that html2text writes its output buffer. I have tried to use the -ascii and -utf8 flags which haven't really made any difference.

I've also tried different ways of setting the input/output of the program such as:

```
html2text <<< $string;
html2text <<< $string > output.txt
```

and of course the documented way of doing it

```
html2text -o $outputTextFile $inputHtmlFile
```

I've even tried loading the output directly into a string in my PHP code and then using file_put_contents to save it (I thought it might be something to do with streams/buffers) but it saves the same way. strangely if I output the text directly onto the command line the output looks ok.

I've now completely run out of ideas, I've spent the last two days trying to work out whats going on with it.

Has anyone had similar issues before?

Thanks

Comment: can you add a link to the html2text library you're using?

Comment: Tivie - I installed it via homebrew, only specifics I can find are that it's version: 1.3.2a

Comment: Check my answer and post the results of the tests I suggest there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So if you run the command `html2text -o file.txt page.html`

- in the shell, it works as expected
- in php, with exec, it produces strange text right?

---

## Troubleshooting

First I would test with a simple test html file such as this one

**file.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
    <span>I'm a simple html file</span>
</body>
</html>
```

I would also create a small php file with just these lines:

**simple.php**

```
<?php
exec('html2text -o file.txt page.html');
```

I would test it in the shell running:

html2text -o file1.txt page.html
   php simple.php

---

If the resulting files **are equal**

1. I would increase the complexity of file.html (always with **local files**) until I was satisfied enough (or something breaks).
2. If 1 works, then I would try with webpages (until something breaks or enough tests were tried)
3. Then I would increase the complexity of the php file, adding a feature at a time, until it breaks.

---

If the resulting files **are different**

1. First I would make sure the same library is being used (php user might be using a different library, maybe). I can do that by using:

   - **[which command](http://ss64.com/osx/which.html)** `which -a html2text` both in the shell and in a php script.
   - using the full path to the bin, for instance: /usr/local/bin/html2text
2. If the results are still different, then I would try to use **[proc_open](http://php.net/manual/en/function.proc-open.php)** instead of exec and check both STDERR and STDOUT for errors or warnings.

Comment: Thanks @Tivie, I will try these and see how I get on, I dont think that its using different packages between PHP and from the command line though. When I said the output is fine in the command line I meant that I'm saving the output file as something like output.txt. If I do less output.txt then it shows perfectly fine. If I echo it on screen or just open the file I get the strange output.

Comment: as an example:

I get this when using less:|<C2><A0>SUPPLIE|<C2><A0>DELIVERY ADDRESS

it shows some strange characters but the rest is fine.

I get this... on screen |_Â_ _SS_UU_PP_PP_LL_II_EE_||_Â_ _DD_EE_LL_II_VV_EE_RR_YY_ _AA_DD_DD_RR_EE_SS_SS

Comment: I tried a number of things to get this resolved, It seemed that most things I tried had the same issue. It was mostly affected by the HTML table generated by Word. I have left it for a while and returned to it.

In the end I upgraded poppler and html2text. Still had some issues with the table headings but I didn't need the information in those as they are always static. 

Since upgrading those packages I am able to read the dynamic data in the HTML and finish the project. 

Many Thanks to @Tivie for his help diagnosing the issue.